# "`" showing in random letters a-z

Tags: java

1.Assignment for class, it picks a random number between 1-26 then converts it to a char eg a=1 z=26, i have done this but when i test the game ` is in the possible answers.

Comment: you´re missng half of your code?

Comment: And is there ever a `z`?

Comment: i dont want to put up all of code it is just if statements and yes there can be a z.

Comment: Please put a minimal version of code, and remove all the extra overflowing comments from the question ...

Comment: read the documentation of the nextInt(int) method: Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value **between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)**. Meaning: number.nextInt(25) will return values from 0 to 24. When you then add 96 to that to create your char the minumum is 96 aka  ` and 120 aka `x`

Comment: It seems the assignment says convert a number to a `char` and your code converts a `char` to a number? Also I don’t understand the point in `charValue+96`. Maybe if you use a character literal instead of the number 96 it will make more sense.

Comment: 96 is for lowercase char, the code for char to number isnt whats causing the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put into the TARGET a value between 0..24:

```
  int TARGET = number.nextInt(25);
```

And later in the code you convert it to char in this way:

```
  int charValue = TARGET; //this is the number you enter
  char TARGETans = (char)(charValue+96); //this is the character you want
```

So will get a char, which ASCII code is from 0+96=96 to 24+96=120

If you check the ASCII codes, 96 is the character ` and 120 is the character x.
You need to generate 26 numbers (number.nextInt(26)) and add 1 to get a..z.

Comment: so how would i implement that?
    int TARGET = number.nextInt(27); ??

Comment: int TARGET = number.nextInt(26)+1; will give you numbers 1..26